# Sending RTP packages on the same port as RTSP

Tags: android, rtsp, vlc, rtp

I'm a little bit confused and I hope you are able to help me. I'm writing rtsp server on my Android. I had a few problems but there were some ways to solve all of them except one.

Description:
I've a application consists of 3 modules RTSP, RTP and UI.
Skipping description of UI. RTSP starts listening on tcp port 55555. Then in VLC I type rtsp://address:55555
Then there is handshake and all RTSP share of headers. Durung share of headers programs sets receive and set ports via RTP and Android application starts to send some bytes but...

Here's the problem:
There is no any image in VLC. So I looked in logs and:

```
main debug: resyncing on rtsp://192.168.1.143:55555
main debug: rtsp://192.168.1.143:55555 is at 2
main debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
main debug: resyncing on rtsp://192.168.1.143:55555
main debug: rtsp://192.168.1.143:55555 is at 2
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'rtsp://192.168.1.143:55555'
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path 'D:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp'
main debug: `rtsp://192.168.1.143:55555' gives access `rtsp' demux `' path `192.168.1.143:55555'
main debug: creating demux: access='rtsp' demux='' location='192.168.1.143:55555' file='\\192.168.1.143:55555'
main debug: looking for access_demux module: 1 candidate
live555 debug: version 2012.09.13
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
live555 debug: RTP subsession 'video/JPEG'
main debug: selecting program id=0
live555 debug: setup start: 0.000000 stop:100.000000
live555 debug: We have a timeout of 600 seconds
live555 debug: spawned timeout thread
live555 debug: play start: 0.000000 stop:100.000000
main debug: using access_demux module "live555"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 155.608 ms - Total 155.608 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 155.608 ms)
main debug: looking for decoder module: 32 candidates
avcodec debug: libavcodec already initialized
avcodec debug: trying to use direct rendering
avcodec debug: allowing 4 thread(s) for decoding
avcodec debug: ffmpeg codec (Motion JPEG Video) started
main debug: using decoder module "avcodec"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.511 ms - Total 1.511 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.511 ms)
main debug: looking for meta reader module: 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in D:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\reader
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in E:\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script E:\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader\filename.luac
main debug: no meta reader module matching "any" could be loaded
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.981 ms - Total 1.981 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.981 ms)
main debug: `rtsp://192.168.1.143:55555' successfully opened
live555 warning: no data received in 10s. Switching to TCP
main debug: removing module "avcodec"
avcodec debug: ffmpeg codec (Motion JPEG Video) stopped
main debug: killing decoder fourcc `MJPG', 0 PES in FIFO
main debug: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
live555 debug: RTP subsession 'video/JPEG'
main debug: looking for decoder module: 32 candidates
avcodec debug: libavcodec already initialized
avcodec debug: trying to use direct rendering
avcodec debug: allowing 4 thread(s) for decoding
avcodec debug: ffmpeg codec (Motion JPEG Video) started
main debug: using decoder module "avcodec"
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.352 ms - Total 1.352 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.352 ms)
live555 debug: setup start: 0.000000 stop:100.000000
live555 debug: play start: 0.000000 stop:100.000000
live555 error: no data received in 10s, aborting
main debug: EOF reached
main debug: finished input
main debug: removing module "avcodec"
avcodec debug: ffmpeg codec (Motion JPEG Video) stopped
main debug: killing decoder fourcc `MJPG', 0 PES in FIFO
main debug: removing module "live555"
main debug: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
main debug: dead input
main debug: changing item without a request (current 2/3)
main debug: nothing to play
qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input
main debug: TIMER input launching for 'rtsp://192.168.1.143:55555' : 161.112 ms - Total 161.112 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 161.112 ms)
qt4 debug: Small
qt4 debug: Saving the simple preferences
main debug: opening config file (D:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming\vlc\vlcrc)
```

And my question: Do I have to send stream on the same port as RTSP? I count on your help cause there is to much code to change.

And forgive me my english, please.

Comment: RTP and RTSP ports can and must be different, nothing wrong with that. How do you send/receive the stream? Paste some code please.

Comment: "live555 warning: no data received in 10s. Switching to TCP" this line is logs tells that UDP data is not received by vlc. can you check if UDP ports are open. also check the SDP response generated by your server, the ports in SDP should be same as the port where u r transmitting data.

Comment: during negotiation via RTSP my server and vlc client sets trasport port and server port so I think vlc ports are open. Connection is set in my LAN by the way and there is no firewall issue. 

On the other side I send SDP as content. I think that's correct becouse connection is finally established. Can you tell me what I  exactly have to put into SDP content?

Answer (score 0):

The streaming video is not arriving to the VLC via udp.
this is why after timeout of 10 seconds it tries a fallback and receive the media via tcp.
You can look at rtp/rtsp/tcp. It's a protocol allowing to send rtp packets on the same socket as the rtsp.

Comment: yeah, so tell me why I need to negotiate port and type(udp/tcp) of send-data connection when data will be send in the same(current) connection instead?